# Winscp "Keep remote directory up to date" save custom Synchronize options as default

Tags: file, sftp, winscp

does someone please know how to get the "Delete Files" in the Synchronize options always checked on ? whenever i want to do a "Keep remote directory" up to date session without having to check the "Delete files" checkbox everytime i want to run it ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's *Use same options next time* checkbox below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much I never thought it would be that easy, I really appreciate your help a lot!